# Django Rest Framework Token Authentication for Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm new to using Django Rest Framework. I have inherited a Django project that has 2 user models: `mods.User` tied to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `players.Member`.

For reasons I can't get into here, they both inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` but involve different information, with only an `email` field common between them.

I am trying to use token authentication for users in `players.Member`. I have created an endpoint `/players_endpoint/register` which successfully adds players to the database. However, after adding the player to the database, the json response comes back with `Cannot assign "<Member: offworld_321>": "Token.user" must be a "User" instance.`

My create view is as follows:

```
class MemberCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MemberCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I was following the tutorial [here](https://iheanyi.com/journal/user-registration-authentication-with-django-django-rest-framework-react-and-redux/)

How can I make it such that upon registration, a player receives a token which will be used for authentication?

Comment: I believe that `Token.user` must actually be a `User` instance.  Not a `Member` instance.  Perhaps your `Member` has an associated `User` that you could reference to retrieve the associated `Token`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `mods.User` is not associated with `players.Member` in a way other than the fact that `mods.User` have admin privilege. Is there another option then besides using `Token.objects.create`?

Comment: The thing is that you're breaking the mold.  The default behavior for authentication in django is using the `User` table and it will automatically tie into a bunch of django middleware.  Standard http Auth, Token Auth, sessions.  Why wouldn't you want to use the standard `User` table/model?  `User`s don't have to have admin/superuser rights.  Anyways, I understand you're working with other people's design decisions, but using a non-standard table for identity is going to require modifying or configuring a bunch of different pieces.  Maybe each `Member` could  have a `User` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it using:

```
user=user.get()
```